# How is a stratum connection secured?

Tags: security, stratum

Does stratum mining use something similar to "https" to secure traffic between the pool and the miners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all traffic is plaintext. The connections are hijackable and attacks against this have occurred in the past where ISPs redirected hashrate to themselves.

Comment: Really?  So there is no way to have username/password logins for the stratum miners either I guess (if it's all plaintext).

Comment: They have logins, but it’s all in plaintext so can be stolen by observers or redirected.

Comment: Oh.  Do you know a more secure mining method for pools?  And how many miners can that method handle on one pool?

Comment: You can wrap a normal stratum socket (or any tcp connection) with SSL using `stunnel`, but this needs to be supported by the pool as well as the client. As far as I know nobody does this presently.

Comment: Thank you but my question was if you know a more secure (than stratum) mining method for pools, and how many miners such pools can handle.  I worry about HTTP because I'm not sure if they handle https and I hear that they don't handle lots of miners at one time.

Comment: Stratum is JSON over raw TCP, there's no HTTP involved in it. There's no other protocols in use, 21.co had a binary protocol based on protobuf but there's nothing using that today. It also, was not encrypted or authenticated.

Comment: I didn't say Stratum uses http.  But http mining is a thing that exists.  I am trying to decide if using it would be preferable from a security standpoint.

Comment: HTTP based mining hasn't existed since 2011 with `getwork` and `getblocktemplate` which never gained any adoption. For very latency sensitive things (i.e., mining) HTTP is a ridiculously bad choice.

Comment: That's helpful.  Some mining pool software on Github offers HTTP so I thought it was a viable alternative.  I wonder why EthOS still requires you to specify stratum if stratum is all that's used?